# failed connect QGIS plugin with access 2007 database using pyodbc

Tags: python-2.7, ms-access-2007, pyodbc, qgis

I m Running Win 7 32 bit and i using python 27, i try to connect ms-access database in my QGIS plugin using pyodbc, but when i launch it i have a following error :

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGISDU~1/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 204, in startPlugin
        plugins[packageName] = package.classFactory(iface)
      File "C:\Users\Mr.Pakde/.qgis2/python/plugins\TestDbase\__init__.py", line 26, in classFactory
        from testdbase import TestDbase
      File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGISDU~1/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 453, in _import
        mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
      File "C:\Users\Mr.Pakde/.qgis2/python/plugins\TestDbase\testdbase.py", line 29, in 
        from testdbasedialog import TestDbaseDialog
      File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGISDU~1/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 453, in _import
        mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
      File "C:\Users\Mr.Pakde/.qgis2/python/plugins\TestDbase\testdbasedialog.py", line 28, in 
        r'DBQ=C:\__tmp\test1.accdb')
```

Error: ('HY024', "[HY024] [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] '(unknown)' is not a valid path.  Make sure that the path name is spelled correctly and that you are connected to the server on which the file resides. (-1023) (SQLDriverConnect); [HY024] [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] '(unknown)' is not a valid path.  Make sure that the path name is spelled correctly and that you are connected to the server on which the file resides. (-1023)")

And i place it like this in my code :

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
from ui_testdbase import Ui_TestDbase
import pyodbc
db = pyodbc.connect(
        r'DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};' +
        r'DBQ=C:\__tmp\test1.accdb')

class TestDbaseDialog(QtGui.QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QDialog.__init__(self)
        # Set up the user interface from Designer.
        self.ui = Ui_TestDbase()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

        Rec_1 = self.ui.btnOke
        QtCore.QObject.connect(Rec_1, QtCore.SIGNAL('clicked()'),self.Compskala)


    def Compskala(self):
        skal1 = self.ui.lineSkal1.text()
        skal2 = self.ui.lineSkal2.text()
        bandskal = ''
        if skal1 == skal2:
            bandskal = 'Kedua Peta dapat dipadukan'
```

I really a newb in this, so can someone give me a help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Substituting backslashes for forward slashes in the filename seems to work:

**Fails**

```
>>> db = pyodbc.connect("DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};" +
                        "DBQ=C:\__tmp\test.accdb")
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "", line 1, in
>    pyodbc.Error: ('HY000', '[HY000] [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft
>   Access Driver] Not a valid  file name. (-1044) (SQLDriverConnect)')

**Succeeds**

```
>>> db = pyodbc.connect("DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};" +
                        "DBQ=C:/__tmp/test.accdb")
>>> connection.getinfo(pyodbc.SQL_SERVER_NAME)
'ACCESS'
```